# Are questions about autonomous rockets on topic?

Tags: discussion

Rocketry is a whole new ball game, but arguably such devices can have robotic elements. Providing they do, would questions asked about them be off topic or beyond the scope of this site?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a word, yes!

Robotics takes many forms - the commonalities are in the ways we solve exciting problems, such as components and techniques, and in the fact that we're solving a certain class of problems. Autonomous *anything* is inherently in the problem-space of robotics. Autonomous rockets are an exciting class of robots that one should absolutely be able to find advice here for, as much as one can find advice for air, land, water surface, underwater, nano, and a variety of other kinds of robots.

Comment: Totally agree. I really look forward to learning more about robot rockets.